# How to create an if statement in selenium that would run if a certain box was not checked?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to run an if statement in selenium that would verify if a checkbox was checked and if it was not perform a certain action. I tried

```
if (selenium.verifyChecked("checkbox")=false){
//perform actions
} else {
//perform different actions
};
```

and it said that that did not work. How would you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Selenium command `isChecked` returns a boolean, so you should be able to do the following:

```
if (selenium.isChecked("checked")) {
  //perform actions
} else {
  //perform different actions
};
```

Comment: thanks. That is what I found out about and have ended up using. So much better than try - catch and verifyChecked();

Answer (score 3):

```
if (selenium.verifyChecked("checkbox")=false){
```

Is wrong. It's assigning false to the return value of the function, which is clearly wrong.

It should be:

```
if (selenium.verifyChecked("checkbox") == false) {
```

Comment: o ok, would not this work also: if (!selenium.verifyChecked("checkbox")) {